# Track down memory leak in Ruby 1.9

Tags: ruby, debugging, memory, garbage-collection, memory-leaks

I have a Ruby application that uses [eventmachine](http://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine) and starts 16 processes that each manage 1000 connections.
Initially each process only uses around 150MB, however after some runtime they consume more and more towards 500MB and I am running out of memory and swap.
The amount of open connections (indicated by `EM.connection_count`) is normal (around 1000 all the time), so there shouldn't really be references to old connections anymore.

Unfortunately, [memprof](http://github.com/ice799/memprof) only runs under Ruby 1.8, so this is not an option in my case.

I don't want to build the [ITAPPMONROBOT](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/ITAPPMONROBOT.aspx) for my application just so I can keep it running 24/7/365. How can I find the memory leak here or how can I help the GC?

Answer (score 0):

There is a known memory leak in 1.9.2's Kernel#method that affects most EM applications. See http://groups.google.com/group/eventmachine/browse_thread/thread/fa56ff02440a624d and http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/3466#note-3